# What techniques can you use to build a web deployment package for a vs2008 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msdeploy

My website is built on an ASP.NET, .NET 3.5 framework.  For various reasons, I'm not in a position to move my project to vs2010.  As a result, I cannot make use of the "Build deployment package" targets that vs2010 supports.

Does anyone know of a way to build a web deployment package (the zip archive that can be imported into IIS 7 via web deploy) with a vs2008 installation (prefer to use msbuild here and I don't require vs2008 integration).

FWIW, I'm trying to avoid publishing it to a temporary server for the purpose of exporting the website.  However, if that's the only option, then so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use msdeploy from the command line and trigger it from your build process: http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/08/16/NoClickWebDeploymentPart2WebDeployAkaMsdeploy.aspx

Comment: Nice answer Jon.  I had been unraveling what was occurring under the covers with msdeploy and was working my way through the arguments.  You saved me a considerable amount of time.  I can't get all of it to work as flawlessly as I'd like, but you've given me a great head start.

Answer (score 0):

I've started putting together a series of tutorials about Web Deploy here - hope they help: http://bilalaslam.com/